# PHP: Execute bash script to start Chromium Browser

Tags: php, bash, shell, sh

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk https://www.google.de/
```

If I run it from terminal `./start_chromium.sh` Chromium opens as expected.

Now I want to run this script using `exec()` in a PHP-file:

```
<?php
   exec('/home/pi/start_chromium.sh');
?>
```

Unfortunately nothing happens.

Checking the error log of Apache2, I see the following error message:

```
(chromium-browser-v7:1992): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:33:27.850: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Lars

Answer (score 1):

This may be an Xauth issue. To test, you can run (from your terminal)

`DISPLAY=:0.0 ; xhosts +`

This is not a recommended long term fix as it completely disabled access control to your X server.